# Como dar formato a conjunto de caracteres recibidos

Tags: c#, visual-studio, formato, serialport

tengo un programita hecho el cual recibo dato mediante SerialPort .Este equipo me arroja los siguientes datos

0.012011 -0.002490 -0.014501 C002

Mi duda es ahora como puedo dividirlos para relacionar cada dato con nombre correspondiente, de la siguiente manera mediante un string format o algo así.

Medida 1 = 0.012011,  Medida 2 = 0.002490, Medida 3 = 0.014501

```
 string datos = puerto.ReadExisting();
 MostrarTexto(DateTime.Now.ToString(" hh:mm dd/MM/yyyy") + "    " + datos + "\r\n");
```

Gracias.

Comment: No termino de entender tu problema. Es como separar una cadena de texto?

Comment: split + delimitador

Comment: Si exactamente, un split, un vector que me permita mostrar los datos como yo quiero, pero el caso es como meto los datos del puerto COM en el array? He probado con string [] datos= puerto.ReadExisting() pero me da error. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar algo como esto.

la cadena que recibes la guardas en una variable string

```
  string dd = "0.012011 -0.002490 -0.014501 C002";
```

Creas un arreglo que para el ejemplo es de 4 posiciones

```
        string[] cadena = new string[3];
```

luego cargas el arreglo haciendo un Split (separación de cadenas) por un un espacio

```
        cadena = dd.Split(' ');
```

Ya estando separadas le das el tratamiento que necesites.

Espero te sirva

Comment: El problema es que recibo datos constantemente, recibo una cadena de esas por minuto, lo ideal por lo tanto sería almacenar la cadena que recibo en el array, no crear un string introduciendo manualmente los datos...Por lo tanto lo que necesito es que en el mismo bucle en el que tengo puerto.readExisting() y muestro los datos necesito tratar esos datos para separarlos y mostrarlos, no se si me explico... Gracias.